# Python Regex Fails on 2 Edge Cases

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am trying to write a regex to split a string into what I call 'terms' (e.g. words, numbers, and surrounding spaces) and 'logical operators' (e.g. <AND, &>, <OR, |>, <NOT,-,~>, <(,{,[,),},]>). For this question, we can ignore the alternative symbols for AND, OR, and NOT, and grouping is just with '(' and ')'.

For example:

```
Frank and Bob are nice AND NOT (Henry is good OR Sam is 102 years old)
```

should be split into this Python list:

```
["Frank and Bob are nice", "AND", "NOT", "(", "Henry is good", "OR", "Sam is 102 years old", ")"]
```

My code:

```
pattern = r"(NOT|\-|\~)?\s*(\(|\[|\{)?\s*(NOT|\-|\~)?\s*([\w+\s*]*)\s+(AND|&|OR|\|)?\s+(NOT|\-|\~)?\s*([\w+\s*]*)\s*(\)|\]|\})?"  
t = re.split(pattern, text)
raw_terms = list(filter(None, t))
```

The pattern works for this test case, the one above, and others,

```
NOT Frank is a good boy AND Joe
raw_terms=['NOT', 'Frank is a good boy', 'AND', 'Joe']
```

but not these:

```
NOT Frank
raw_terms = ['NOT Frank']
NOT Frank is a good boy
raw_terms=['NOT Frank is a good boy']
```

I have tried changing the two \s+ to \s*, but not all test cases passed. I am not a regex expert (this one is the most complicated one I have tried).

I am hoping someone can help me understand why these two test cases fail, and how to fix the regex so all the test cases pass.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
re.split(r'\s*(\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|[()])\s*', string)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/SiMV7R/1).

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      AND                      'AND'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      OR                       'OR'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      NOT                      'NOT'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [()]                     any character of: '(', ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##RY49C8IwGIT3/orbmoiIH5sgoog4tVDdrENqowZrEt68HQr97zWi4Hg8dw/nO344uxgG8/KOGKSTwGTsHSuke1L2CWVrbF0FRRrWXDU22Q5ZfoI4aEsdTMDduRp5gaN6feJsOkenFQW4ppZp4lr2LUcj6UnwjWFBaRlGoqzEehltfV70USjLqj8LeZGRpWN8f8j/ujGBxc00rElkzuoxvkjKxMcqi18chjc):

```py
import re
string = 'Frank and Bob are nice AND NOT (Henry is good OR Sam is 102 years old)'
output = re.split(r'\s*(\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|[()])\s*', string)
output = list(filter(None, output))
print(output)
```

**Results**: `['Frank and Bob are nice', 'AND', 'NOT', '(', 'Henry is good', 'OR', 'Sam is 102 years old', ')']`

Comment: Great solution! I don't completely understand how it works. If you group but don't capture the AND/OR/NOT/(), how does it end up in the output list? Regexs make my brain hurt....

Comment: @user1045680 `(\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|[()])` **is** a capturing group, `re.split` adds all matches to the results.

Comment: I tried adding back in the alternate logical operators (&, |, ~, -) and alternate grouping characters ([]{}) and all the tests with the alternate characters failed. I tried \s*(\b(?:AND|OR|NOT|&|\||-|~)\b|[(){}[]])\s* What am I missing?

Comment: I played around with your solution and was able to add back the alternate characters.  The new regex is `\s*(\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|[()&\~\-\|{}\[\]])\s*`

Comment: @user1045680 Use `\s*(\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|[][()&~|{}-])\s*`, see [proof](https://regex101.com/r/SiMV7R/2).